# Is there a way to create a config file for a custom protocol in Wireshark, using Lua?

Tags: lua, wireshark, preferences

everyone. I've built a custom protocol dissector for Wireshark, that have some preferences of it's own. As of this moment I've succeed to add prefs like textboxes, checkboxes etc., programmatically, using Lua. Now I want to dynamically allow the user to add some custom configurations in the protocol's preferences, like in the attached image.

Can you help me do that, if there's a way, preferably in Lua?

[image: Custom protocol configuration]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [Wireshark Lua Preferences API](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html/#lua_class_Pref) doesn't provide a User Access Table (UAT) preference, which is what would be needed here I think.  You could open a [Wireshark Issue](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/issues) asking for Lua UAT preference support though.  In the meantime, it *may* be possible to read the parameters from a file directly from your Lua dissector, but you won't be able to edit/change those parameters like you can with other preferences.  It *might* be possible to add a [TextWindow](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html/#lua_class_TextWindow) for displaying the parameters and allowing users to change them, but that solution won't be integrated with your Lua dissector and you'll likely need to reload the Lua dissector in order to pick up the changes, which *possibly* could be automated whenever the user changes a parameter.

There may be some user-contributed Lua examples on the Wireshark wiki and elsewhere that could offer some help?  See:

- [Contrib](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/wikis/Contrib)
- [Examples](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/wikis/Lua/Examples)
- [Issue 16795](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/issues/16795) (Example [tap-subnets.lua](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/uploads/4f845c6d98870305fbdf952b5084db86/tap-subnets.lua) file)

Perhaps there's another way to solve this altogether, but nothing else comes to mind.  You might want to inquire at [Wireshark's Q&A Site](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/) though in case anyone else from that community has some further advice for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.I saw some of the supported protocols are using UAT, but i suppose they are built in components of Wireshark.